# angular resource's cache doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add caching to a resource, but at each call, a new ajax request would be made. Here:

```
app.factory('States', function($resource,$locale,$cacheFactory) {
    var cache = $cacheFactory('statesCache');
    var StatesService = $resource( "api/ref/states-:country", {}, {
        query: {
            cache: cache, //With true it doesn't work either
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        }
    });
    return {
        getList: function( country ) {
        console.log( cache.info() );
            return StatesService.query({
                country: (country || "CA").toLowerCase()
            });
        }
    }
});
```

then each call to `States.getList( "CA" );` triggers a new Http request. The console says each time that the custome cache size is still 0: `Object {id: "statesCache", size: 0}`

Angular version <del>is v1.2.0-rc.3</del> was 1.0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was Chrome didn't invalidated the cache for the angular files. It was still loading angular 1.0.8.

I've cleaned the cache and decently updated angular-resource version, now it works.